# Local vs. Global list in Django

Tags: python, django, list, local

I'm saving a **list** of values in Django using JSONField, taken from a daily survey. The `List` model is saving incorrectly whether I call it globally or locally in my views. Here is my model:

```
class List(Model):
score_list = JSONField(default=list)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.score_list

class Answers(Model):
responder = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
def __str__(self):
    return self.score
```

While my `Answers` model is saving correctly, I can't figure out how to save the `List` model. Calling `List` globally `(l = list())` in views.py leads to a single list shared amongst all users. Calling it locally creates a new list for every value that is added, instead of adding these values to a single list for each user. Here is views.py:

```
@login_required
def add(request):
    l = List()
    r = Answers()
    r.responder = request.user
    l.user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_option = (request.POST['rating'])
        list_length = len(l.score_list)
        if selected_option == 'option1':
            r.score = 1
        elif selected_option == 'option2':
            r.score = 2
        elif selected_option == 'option3':
            r.score = 3
        elif selected_option == 'option4':
            r.score = 4
        elif selected_option == 'option5':
            r.score = 5
        else:
            return HttpResponse(400, 'Invalid form')
    l.score_list.append(r.score)
    r.save()
    l.save()

    return redirect(add)

context = {
    'r' : r,
}
return render(request, 'rating/add.html', context)
```

I would think that using a OneToOneField would ensure that each list has a unique user. Instead, I am getting a single list with the user field being updated depending on who was the last to take the survey. How can I get a separate list saving for each user?

Comment: Please do not make a global list. A global state is a (severe) anti-pattern: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: Did you tested with ForeignKey ? You want to save every list with own user..